# custom sort a string list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, dart

I have a list (in flutter):

```
loadedSummaryList = [
         'BILD',
         'DRIT',
         'VIMN',
         'WELT',
         'FLUTTER',
         'ALL'
       ];
```

, and I want to sort this list like:

```
['WELT', 'BILD', 'VIMN', 'DRIT', 'ALL', 'FLUTTER']
```

in other words, I want to sort the first four elements of the list always like 'WELT', 'BILD', 'VIMN', 'DRIT', and then alphabetically.
I tried it like this:

```
  List<String> sortList = ['WELT', 'BILD', 'VIMN', 'DRIT'];
       
  loadedSummaryList.sort(
          (a, b) {
            int aIntex = sortList.indexOf(a.name);
            int bIntex = sortList.indexOf(b.name);
            return aIntex.compareTo(bIntex);
          },
        );
```

which returns

```
['ALL', 'FLUTTER', 'WELT', 'BILD', 'VIMN', 'DRIT'];
```

but actually, I want to have it like:

```
['WELT', 'BILD', 'VIMN', 'DRIT', 'ALL', 'FLUTTER']
```

could someone help me, please?
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us the logic behind Welt will come first then blid then vimn then drit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, `indexOf` returns `-1` when the element is not in the list, therefore it will put those in front. A solution for that is to change it to a higher number in that case.
Secondly, you also need to sort them alphabetically, which you don't do now. You can do that by doing a `compareTo` on the strings themselves in the case that the first `compareTo` returns `0`.

final result:

```
loadedSummaryList.sort(
      (a, b) {
    int aIntex = sortList.indexOf(a);
    int bIntex = sortList.indexOf(b);
    if (aIntex == -1) aIntex = sortList.length;
    if (bIntex == -1) bIntex = sortList.length;
    var result = aIntex.compareTo(bIntex);
    if (result != 0) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return a.compareTo(b);
    }
  },
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just sort them and merge them into one.

```dart
void main() {
  var all = <String>['BILD', 'DRIT', 'VIMN', 'WELT', 'FLUTTER', 'ALL'];
  var sort = <String>['WELT', 'BILD', 'VIMN', 'DRIT'];
  
  // It depends on how you want list sorting in the end result.
  // You can sort both lists if you want.
  all.sort();
  //sort.sort(); 
  
  var result = sort.followedBy(all).toSet().toList();
  
  print(result); // [WELT, BILD, VIMN, DRIT, ALL, FLUTTER]
}
```